# Replacing strings in pandas data frame using dictionary without overwriting

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dictionary

I am trying to convert a pandas data frame with a column populated with values such as this:

```
df['Alteration']

Q79K,E17K
Q79K,E17K
T315I
```

And would like to convert the single letter amino acid to its triple letter code to look more like this:

```
Gln79Lys,Glu17Lys
Gln79Lys,Glu17Lys
Thr315Ile
```

So far I have tried to use a dictionary using regex expression as the keys, such as this:

```
AA_code = {re.compile('[C]'): 'Cys',re.compile('[D]'): 'Asp', 
re.compile('[S]'): 'Ser',re.compile('[Q]'): 'Gln',re.compile('[K]'): 'Lys', 
re.compile('[I]'): 'Ile',re.compile('[P]'): 'Pro',re.compile('[T]'): 'Thr', 
re.compile('[F]'): 'Phe',re.compile('[N]'): 'Asn',re.compile('[G]'): 'Gly', 
re.compile('[H]'): 'His',re.compile('[L]'): 'Leu',re.compile('[R]'): 'Arg', 
re.compile('[W]'): 'Trp',re.compile('[A]'): 'Ala',re.compile('[V]'): 'Val', 
re.compile('[E]'): 'Glu',re.compile('[Y]'): 'Tyr',re.compile('[M]'): 'Met'}
```

And the following code to replace based on the dictionary:

```
df['Replacement'] = dfx2['Alteration'].replace(AA_code, regex=True)
```

However, I am getting some strange behaviour where the replace function is over-writing the values, to look more like this:

```
Glyln79Leuys,Glu17Leuys
Glyln79Leuys,Glu17Leuys
Thr315Ile
```

From what I understand, the Glyln is derived from the code first changing the Q to Gln, and then the **G** in **G**ln is being overwritten by the G : Gly key : value pair in the dictionary to get Glyln. Is there some way to fix this??

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a single lookup table and then use it in a callable in `Series.str.replace`, eg:

```
import pandas as pd

lookup = {
    'Q': 'Gln',
    'K': 'Lys',
    'E': 'Glu',
    'G': 'Gly'
    # needs completing...
}

s = pd.Series(['Q79K,E17K', 'Q79K,E17K', 'T315I'])
s.str.replace('([{}])'.format(''.join(lookup)), lambda m: lookup[m.group(1)])
```

Gives you:

```
0    Gln79Lys,Glu17Lys
1    Gln79Lys,Glu17Lys
2                T315I
```

Answer (score 0):

Jon's answer is great. Following his input, another way to do it would be this,

```
import pandas as pd

lookup = {
    'Q': 'Gln',
    'K': 'Lys',
    'E': 'Glu',
    'G': 'Gly'
     # needs completing...
}

s = pd.Series(['Q79K,E17K', 'Q79K,E17K', 'T315I'])
s.apply(lambda row: "".join([lookup[x] if x in lookup else x for x in row]))
```

or, as suggested by @Jon Clements in the comment,

`s.apply(lambda row: "".join([lookup.get(x,x) for x in row]))`

which gives you,

```
0    Gln79Lys,Glu17Lys
1    Gln79Lys,Glu17Lys
2                T315I
dtype: object
```

Comment: If you're going to go for that approach then `lookup.get(x, x) for x in row` is a way of avoiding the explicit if/else check...

Comment: Amazing. I was looking up how to avoid the if/else check myself. Thanks!